# Can I debug CUDA on the device that drives the display output?

Tags: cuda, nvidia, nsight

I develop on VS2012. I have 3 monitors connected to my pc with one GTX 960 graphic card.

I knew that it's impossible to debug CUDA on the same device that drives the display output. Maybe I'm reading it wrong, but when I go to `NSight->Windows->System Info->Display Devices`, I can see that the monitor uses my graphic card. Since I have only one graphic card and I can debug (as the image shows in CUDA WarpWatch1) I deduct that either I do can debug on the same device that drives the display output or it uses my built-in `Intel HD Graphics` but doesn't show it in the Display Device [image].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite what you have apparently read somewhere, CUDA (and NSight) has supported debugging on GPUs with the WDDM driver on active display GPUs for a number of years. You can see the exact matrix of supported hardware, drviers and debugging modes in the documentation [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/developertools/desktop/nsight/system_requirements.htm#Compute_Debugger_Support).

When CUDA was first introduced, debugging was limited to non-display cards. However, this limitation was removed on Windows and Linux using more recent hardware some time ago.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. Let's say you have only one graphic card and it's used for your monitor. Now, you want to debug code that runs on the same graphic card. I read that you cannot DEBUG code that runs on the same graphic card that also is used for your monitor. You can use it to run your code, but not to debug it. If you want to debug you need either to run it on a different graphic card or make sure that that graphic card is not used for your monitor.

Comment: No I haven't. Read what I linked to. You can debug on an active display GPU in NSight and that is what is happening here